# i am change the background color of container using hexcode but showing error

Tags: flutter, containers, background-color, flutter-container

Container(
color: Color('#260033'),
height: 150.0,
width: double.infinity,
child: Column(

i want to use hex code to change the container color.pls help me regarding this.

Container(
color: Color('#260033'), // showing error on this line
height: 150.0,
width: double.infinity,
child: Column(

i want to change the background of container using this hex color code but unable to this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter you have to use `Color(0xff)` with your hex code.

if you want to use the color `#260033`- use `Color(0XFF260033)`
`FF` represents full opacity. if you want to change the opacity replace `FF` with values in [this table](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/8710f6f752f6a0f2cae13abb538f0e8e#hex-opacity-values)

```
        Container(
           color:Color(0xff260033),
           child: Text("some text"),
                 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In flutter to give the hex code as color you can use this statement:

```
color: Color(0xff260033),
```

Answer (score 0):

### You cannot use strings as color.

You should use function `Color` to create color using hexadecimal `int` number.
**The Color class expects an ARGB integer**. Since you try to use it with an RGB value, represent it as `int` and prefix it with `0xff`. In your case:

```
Container( color: Color(0xFF260033), ...
```